# Can I test Exchange Web Services off Office 365

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I am looking to get involved with Exchange Web services. Is Office 365 a good place to do this.  I don't have the time and infrastructure to install exchange in the office to test everything.  So is office 365 a good test bed?
Rico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Office 365 to test the WebService. It's very easy to use once it is set up and you get a 30 day test account.

Limitation: To get AutoDiscover to work, you either need to fiddle around with your DNS settings, or follow Glens advice on this page: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/03e5e902-1de1-43b9-a86d-13e3d826c920